# Trying to upload image into firebase but failed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to add an image into firebase storage but whenever trying to upload every time gets failed (Every time runs else part toast message "Something went wrong"). I am adding code here...

```
private void uploadImage() {
        pd.setMessage("Uploading...");
        pd.show();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50 ,baos);
        byte[] finalimg = baos.toByteArray();
        final StorageReference filePath;
        filePath = storageReference.child("Notice").child(finalimg+"jpg");
        final UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(finalimg);
        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(UploadNotice.this, new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    downloadUrl = String.valueOf(uri);
                                    uploadData();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(UploadNotice.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

***Please anyone tell me what is problem in my code?*** **How I can resolve it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing the `.` in before `jpg` extension.

`child` argument needs to be a `String`, you are concatenating a `byte[]` with `String`.

Anyway, if you need to know what the error is:

```
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e("error", exception.getMessage());
```

Comment: Bro, Sorry but I didn't understand it can you please implement it in my above code and give me solution.

Comment: Just add this listener as is to your uploadTask.